# Cron loop best practices

Tags: cron, performance, disk

I wrote a script that loops through every file in a folder and performs a simple operation on each file. That folder will almost always be empty and only occasionally contain a file, but I'd like the script to run automatically (and relatively promptly) when a file does appear. What's the best practice to do that?

Right now, I just have cron running the script every minute. Is there a problem doing it that way? If I just leave that going long-term, will that make a difference in longevity of the drive?

Thanks!

Comment: If your system has systemd I believe that can trigger services when files change. I suspect that also uses inotify. https://www.linux.com/tutorials/systemd-services-monitoring-files-and-directories/

Comment: @roaima incron was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`incrond` can run a command when a file appears. It uses `inotify` underneath.

As has been pointed out in a comment, `systemd` can also [monitor a directory and trigger actions](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/systemd-services-monitoring-files-and-directories/).

```
[Unit] 
Wants= my.service 

[Path] 
DirectoryNotEmpty= /path/to/monitored/directory
```